# What ascii characters do I use to get Esc+Insert?

Tags: excel, ascii

What ascii characters do I use to get Esc+Insert?

I am wanting to copy and paste from Excel into a terminal program (Reflection) but this particular screen requires Esc+Insert to enter a new line of data.

Comment: I assume that you are using Excel VBA and activating the terminal program. If so, then look up `SendKeys` in the VBA language reference.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up activating excel via the terminal program and using SendKeys. Its a bit complicated for others in the office who aren't tech savvy as its not just copy and paste, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
application.SendKeys "{ESCAPE}{INSERT}"
```

[]´s

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I was hoping to put the sequence in a cell rather than use VBA, but after a bit more looking around I suspect this is the only way.